# Keyboard map/layout with Mac-style deadkeys?

Tags: keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I write in English and French, so I'd like to have an English (QWERTY) keymap that still lets me type accented letters easily. I don't like the English-International keyboard because that requires additional keystrokes to type single and double quotes, carets, etc.

Apple has always had what I consider the best deadkey solution: Option-e is a deadkey for the acute accent, Option-u for the umlaut, etc. A keymap like this exists for Linux (using AltGr instead of Option).

Is there one for MS Windows (10), or would it be possible to create one using MS's own keyboard layout creation tool (I haven't yet discovered how to define a deadkey that isn't a single keystroke in that editor)?

Answer (score 1):

You may remap the keyboard as you wish using
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
You can do any combination you like with much more freedom than when using the
keyboard layout creation tool.

For "dead" keys you can be creative with using modifier keys such as the AltGr,
or you may also use the numpad keys when Numpad is on.

Here is an example AutoHotkey script that maps the upper row of the Numpad,
keys `789`, to keys `éèê`:

```
numpad7:: é
numpad8:: è
numpad9:: ê
```

A AutoHotkey script is easy to modify, and you may also take it with you to
other computers.

Many tutorials are available on the AutoHotkey website, and many examples on its
very active user community.